# Colocar ImageView con ProgressBar al borde de un RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml

Necesito colocar el `ImageView` (tiene un `ProgressBar` encima) al final del `RelativeLayout` (encima del borde). He logrado hacerlo con un `FloatingActionButton` pero, al parecer el `ImageView` se comporta diferente.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:alpha="1.0"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            tools:src="@drawable/default_post_photo" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/playRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/photoImageView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/photoImageView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_play"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play2_white_24dp" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/playProgressBar"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icon_play"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon_play"
                android:theme="@style/CircularProgress"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/shareFloatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si al `ImageView` le agrego `android:layout_marginBottom="-16dp"` se esconde la mitad, es decir, solo se visualiza la mitad del `ImageView` en pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Había pensado colocar otro `FloatingActionButton` en lugar de un `ImageView` pero, no encontraba la forma de agregarle un `ProgressBar` encima.

Espero puedan ayudarme y gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Y si lo colocas fuera de ese relative layout? es decir, que lo pongas a la altura del botón de share.

Comment: @x4mp73r He probado de todo y no logro hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba colocando esto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:alpha="1.0"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            tools:src="@drawable/default_post_photo" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/photoImageView"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/playRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/photoImageView"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/shareFloatingActionButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="-28dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_play"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play2_white_24dp" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/playProgressBar"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icon_play"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon_play"
                android:theme="@style/CircularProgress"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/shareFloatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/photoImageView"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-28dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="-28dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Texto para rellenar"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Texto para rellenar"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Texto para rellenar"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Lo que hice fue colocar un view transparente y colocar debajo de imageview el boton y colocar la mitad del tamaño del objeto en marginTop = -28dp.

Comment: Hola compañero, gracias por tratar de ayudarme. He probado tu código y el `ImageView` se visualiza correctamente encima del borde pero, el `FloatingActionButton` no, este está debajo de la foto (prueba: http://oi68.tinypic.com/2e67nr5.jpg). Además de esto, el espacio transparente que has puesto debajo se vuelve inutilizable y requiero ese espacio ya que tengo unos cuantos `TextView` ahí. Debido a ese espacio transparente, todos mis `TextView` se han desplazado más hacia abajo.

Comment: Revisa el nuevo codigo q agregue deberia funcionar asi, ademas que agregue los texto que mencionas